# SAS Invalid data set name

Tags: unix, sas

We're using SAS V 9.04.01M4P110916

I'm accessing Data from a defined Library called:

```
%let us_mkt = server='sandntz.bkrgc.net' database='IDP_PRD_US_MARKETING' port=5480 user=&db2_idx. password=&win_pwdx.

libname ROLAP netezza &us_mkt. schema=USER_ROLAP

data ROLAP.USER_ROLAP.SALES_TBL;
 set ROLAP.SALES_TBL;
run;
```

I'm getting the following errror message:

```
263        data ROLAP.USER_ROLAP.SALES_TBL;
                ______________________________
                211
ERROR 211-185: Invalid data set name.

264           set ROLAP.SALES_TBL;
265        /*   set USER_ROLAP.SALES_TBL; */
266        run;
```

If ROLAP is the correctly defined library and USER_ROLAP is the correctly defined schema. Why am I getting this error? Also FYI: Any other combination of these names gives an error where the program won't read data. I understand that ROLAP.USER_ROLAP is redundant but if I just say ROLAP.SALES_TBL in the data statement: I get the following error. Here is how the documentation says I should define it.

```
263        data ROLAP.SALES_TBL;
264           set USER_ROLAP.SALES_TBL;
ERROR: Libref 'USER_ROLAP' exceeds 8 characters.
ERROR: File WORK.SALES_TBL.DATA does not exist.
265        /*   set USER_ROLAP.SALES_TBL; */
266        run;
```

Why am I getting these errors?

Answer (score 3):

SAS libnames are restricted to 8 characters and schema name(in this case USER_ROLAP) is not part of SAS libname.

```
 libname ROLAP netezza &us_mkt. schema=USER_ROLAP;
```

pointer for below whole thing is  ROLAP or whatever you need you define within 8 characters and  where Netezza is engine name and other things in libname related to server database name and schema name of netezza. SAS does not understand schema names separately

```
 netezza &us_mkt. schema=USER_ROLAP
```

your table names will be

```
  Rolap.tablename
```

Edit1: looks like you want to move the data to SAS then please use bulkunload=YES option as shown below. This will move data quickly from Netezza to SAS

```
   data work.SALES_TBL;
   SET ROLAP.SALES_TBL (bulkunload=YES); 
   RUN;
```

Comment: I basically have my answer as the following.

data work.SALES_TBL;
SET ROLAP.SALES_TBL;
RUN;
Thanks!

Comment: so you are creating dataset in SAS not in netezza

Comment: Yup. Just so long as I have access to it. So If I wouyld have said 
   "data ROLAP.SALES_TBL_2;"
Would it have created a Table in Netezza?

Comment: yes it does create in netezza, but why do you have same dataset twice in netezza, do you have where clause or something like that

Comment: i mean in same database you will be having two same tables, which will take up space, but does not serve any purpose or do you want to move something from SAS to netezza